# How can I make SWIG for Lua create a binary operators with a scalar as left argument and custom class on the right?

Tags: lua, swig

The SWIG documentation shows how to overload operators. The example they have is of a Complex class and they show how to overload the operator+. They also have an example talking about mixing double and Complex. However the example as given, though it defines
`Complex operator+(double, const Complex &)`, it only works for complex+double. 
Take the following example:

```
a = Complex(2,3);
b = a+3;
print(b);
b = 3+a;
print(b);
```

The output is as follows:

```
<Complex userdata: 7FFE30C47438>
Could not execute script file test.lua: Error in Complex::__add__ (arg 1), expected 'Complex *' got 'number'
```

The first line of output is the result of the first call to `print(b)`. The call to `3+a` fails.

How can I make SWIG generate code that will work when the left hand side is a scalar and the Complex is on the right hand side?